# How, according to the Catholic Church, can God order genocide even though the Church has declared such a situation impossible?

Tags: catholicism, textual-discrepancies, violence

Quoting Veritatis Splendor:

> Reason attests that there are objects of the human act which are by their nature "incapable of being ordered" to God, because they radically contradict the good of the person made in his image. (...) The Second Vatican Council itself, in discussing the respect due to the human person, gives a number of examples of such acts: "Whatever is hostile to life itself, such as any kind of homicide, genocide, abortion, euthanasia and voluntary suicide, (...)"

[Veritatis Splendor, 80](http://w2.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_jp-ii_enc_06081993_veritatis-splendor.html)

So I believe that we can say that according to the teaching of the Catholic Church, genocide can never be ordered to be carried out by God and committing it is always evil.

Still, in the Bible we have examples of <s>God</s>**Moses** *(see comments)* ordering His believers to commit genocide:

> But in the cities of those nations which the LORD, your God, is giving you as your heritage, you shall not leave a single soul alive. You must doom them all - the Hittites, Amorites, Canaanites, Perizzites, Hivites and Jebusites - as the LORD, your God, has commanded you, lest they teach you to make any such abominable offerings as they make to their gods, and you thus sin against the LORD, your God.

[Deuteronomy 20, 16-18](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0839/__P4Z.HTM)

This most obviously satisfies the definition of genocide, as stated by the United Nations:

> Genocide is defined in Article 2 of the Convention on the Prevention and Punishment of the Crime of Genocide (1948) as "any of the following acts committed with intent to destroy, in whole or in part, a national, ethnical, racial or religious group, as such: killing members of the group; (...)"

[OFFICE OF THE UN SPECIAL ADVISER ON THE PREVENTION OF GENOCIDE (OSAPG)](http://www.un.org/ar/preventgenocide/adviser/pdf/osapg_analysis_framework.pdf)

There seems to be incongruity in Catholic teaching here. How does the Church explain the fact that while it declares it impossible for God to order genocide, such an order from God seems to be described in the Bible?

Comment: I need to note here that according to one priest I met the violent deeds of the Israelites against these nations was indeed an atrocious genocide, and God has never ordered it; instead, the Israelites wrote these passages in an attempt to justify their evils. The Bible is not to be read literally, and especially not the Old Testament, which instead is a story of how God was able to show some truths about Himself and about the morality among the evils of those times.

Comment: However, I am very unsure about this explanation - the Bible is supposed to be infallible according to Christianity, and such explanation is very short of accusing the Bible of containing intentional lies.

Comment: "_the Israelites wrote these passages in an attempt to justify their evils_" So, it's not the inspired word of God?

Comment: @Geremia IIUC, according to that priest, the inspired world of God is how God managed to turn the evils of genocide to show some truths the 1st commandment, how evil will be eventually defeated and good will triumph, etc.

Comment: @Geremia A random statement from the Internets: "In one of the encyclicals the Pope clearly stated that the Bible may contain motifs and myths of surrounding peoples, but the Biblical authors, under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit, have adequately selected them and described". In that case, perhaps this explanation from that pries is possible...

Comment: @Geremia Subsequent, very similar explanation from the internets: In the Deuteronomy  it is Moses who orders this, not God. Moses was a child of his epoch, his own moralities were shaped by his times. War was necessery, otherwise the nation of Isreal would not survive, not to mention the 1st Commandment and the atrocious crimes of Canaanities; however the crimes the Isreal committed during these wars were the interpretation of God's oders, not God's orders themselves. Also it is important to note that a full genocide did not occur. At least this is how I understand what I read.

Comment: Know why "Genocide" isn't in the Bible?  Because the term didn't exist then.  You're applying newer definitions retroactively.  It's like saying, "why does God say that we don't need to perform a blood sacrifice but they did it in the Old Testament"

Comment: Is  the Bible is supposed to be infallible according to the Catholic Church?  I think you're painting Christianity with a broad brush.

Comment: @TheFreemason Ofc the term "genocide" didn't exist by these times; but this is irrelevant. The Church considers "genocide" as inherently evil, IIUC this means it will always be evil no matter the circumstances, including but not limited to times, the culture, or the understanding of morality of those peoples. This is within the definition of moral absolutism, as opposed to moral relativism according to which genocide wouldn't be evil just because these people didn't consider it evil or weren't evil operating such a term.

Comment: You're applying Veritatis Splendor, 80 retroactively and looking to debate.  My peace be with you, good day.

Comment: @TheFreemason According to the Catholic Church, Holy Scripture is completely inerrant (free from any error). See [the magisterial quotes here](http://www.suscipedomine.com/forum/index.php?topic=4744.msg90272#msg90272).

Answer (score 1):

God makes plenty of commands that are recorded in Holy Scripture. Why would Deut. 20:16-18 be an exception?

The [original Douay-Rheims translation](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4511) of Deut. 20 prefaces this chapter with

> Lawful wars are to be undertaken with courage and confidence.

The war is lawful because it is defensive. It is to defend the people against the great spiritual threats of the idolaters, whom the Lord knows would tempt the people of God to violate the 1st Commandment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but IMHO it is hard to hold such a point... 1) The Israelites were not native to these terrains, so they were actually invaders; 2) This is so close to the ideology of ISIL... if such wars are lawful, then the only thing wrong in jihad is that Mohammad was a false prophet, doing same things under the Holy Cross would be good? 3) Even if this war of Isrealites was lawful - your argument fails to acknowledge how, according to VatII and Veritatis Splendor genocide is inherently evil, therefore justifiable under no circumstances and "incapable of being ordered to God"...

Comment: @gaazkam I think you want a conversation or discussion and not an answer.  Please consider using [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room).

Comment: @TheFreemason I think you're exaggerating. I want an answer. Yet I can't accept an answer about which I have strong doubts; comments are exactly where I am meant to post such doubts. Though I could agree that perhaps I should post these "other ideas" Im mentioning as one of the possible answers, this could clean up the comments section below my question. Ill do this in a while.

Comment: @gaazkam Re: (1): v. 10: "If at any time thou come to win a city, thou shalt first offer peace." If they abide by that, they are not invaders. (2): Jihadists think they can force conversions. That's quite different from those who first offer peace. (3): Killing people just because they are a certain race is evil; that is genocide, racism. Killing in defense is not intrinsically evil; it is just.

Comment: @gaazkam Also, was it race that made someone a Hethite, Amorrheite, Chananite,  Pherezeite,  and Jebusite? Or was it their (idolatrous) beliefs? If the latter, then killing them certainly would not be called genocide.

Comment: Firstly, according to Deuteronomy, the Israelites were only to offer peace to distant cities; closer cities were to be erredicated. Secondly, according to this "peace offering", the inhabitants of these cities were to be subjected to force labor and made to tribute. To put this in other words, this peace offering was much like this: "We come to your lands and will be the new rulers of your lands. Surrender to us and become our slaves, and we will let you live; defend yourselves, and die." I'd call this an invasion, not coming with peace!

Comment: As I noted in my question, genocide does not necessarily only mean killing people of a certain race, but also of a certain religion! Therefore, killing a pagan only on the basis of himself being a pagan (Hethite, Amorrheite, Chananite, Pherezeite, Jebusite, etc) definitely **is** genocide. What the current jihadists are saying is: "You're not a Muslim; become Muslim or die!". What the Israelites were saying was: "Since you're a pagan, you must die!" I'd say that was perhaps even more harsh...

Comment: @gaazkam Etymologically, genocide is the killing (_-cide_) of a race (_geno-_). The UN definition you quote is so broad that any act of war of one nation against another could be considered genocide. Where does a magisterial document from the Church define genocide so broad as this?

Answer (score 0):

- Those peoples were opposed to God and as the divine Judge, He is just in sentencing their destruction.
- The land belonged to Israel.  God set it aside for them as part of His promise to Abraham.  Their refusal to vacate the land without a fight justifies their destruction.  Just as you would be justified in destroying an intruder to your house, even if they moved in while you were overseas for a year.
- God decried their destruction because of their practices and behaviors.  The few that were willing to change were not destroyed.  The Gibeonites and Rahab for example.
- Keep in mind also that these peoples were distant cousins, some 15 or so generations removed.  Destruction of a branch of a family may not fit the full definition of genocide.

The behaviors described by Veritatis Splendor as human acts cannot be attributed to God, because His acts are divine.  The peoples of the land of Canaan were wicked and opposed to God.  Israel was His instrument of judgement on the peoples of the land of Canaan.  Their actions were ordained by God to cleanse the land and to protect Israel.

If a judge sentences someone to be executed, the executioner is not committing murder.  If the judge sentences a group of people to be executed, it is still not murder.  The scale does not matter.  With human judges, the motives may be questionable, but with God, the motives are always right.